# Jquery ui "revert" position on modal form Cancel

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a group of elements that can be dragged (and dropped if need be), when the user stops the drag action i need a form to appear(either by drag:stop or drop) to update the object moved, if the user Cancels the Modal Form, I'd like the item to "revert" back to it original position where the user dragged it from. So it seems there a few options:

It's the proverbial "chicken and egg" scenario here for me, I'm sure you'll be quick to tell me its not the case at all, but is it: drag and drop on success, or drop and "do something" while using `revert:invalid`?

```
$("#draggable").draggable({  
 //revert: true, 
 revert: "invalid",//only works with drop
 cursor: "hand" ,
 grid: [ 44,0 ],
 axis: "x",                     
 cursor: "move",     
 stop: function(ev, ui){    
   //Do Something here??                          

       $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
             "Yep": function() {
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
             "Nope": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                   // ...or Do something here?
                }
              }
            });


      } 
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/olawas/1/edit

Comment: Have you thought about simply refreshing the page from the server?

Comment: I did, but it seem like a lot of code to re-initialize everything (that may be my lack of understanding of live/ready)..but these elements have several things they do so a refresh would be a challenge and a literal page refresh would kill the user experience

Comment: I'm convinced it will be an option like ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true); or something simple, but I can't seem to piece it together..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have think this before, but why you don't save the values of
css { top, left, bottom, right } from the "dragged" element, in the "drag" event and the "start" event so in stop you just decide wich one the element should keep.

[It's something like this what you want to do ?](http://jsbin.com/olawas/6/edit)

Comment: This is good! it seems to work well in the example, I'll implement it today and post back here how it went. Thank you!   I'm really surprised there is not a built in function in Jq-ui considering how much thought they put into the revert:option:invlaid on drop. Thanks again, your solution allows me to move on.